# Previous Detect JSON Solutions Not Working

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am trying to create a function that can universally sanitize AJAX request input coming into my server. Thus far I have created this:

```
function sanitize($variable) {
    switch(gettype($variable)) {
        case "string":
            ////
            $variable = trim($variable);
            $variable = stripslashes($variable);
            $variable = htmlspecialchars($variable);
            break;
        case "array":
            foreach($variable as $key => $property) {
                $variable[$key] = sanitize($property);
            }
            break;
        case "object":
            foreach($variable as $key => $property) {
                $variable->$key = sanitize($property);
            }
            break;
    }
    return $variable;
}
```

This works wonderfully to fully sanitize even nested arrays, objects, and strings that could be passed through.  However, I wanted to add JSON parsing support on the line that has been commented out, so I took to the internet for solutions. I tried each of these three proposed solutions in the commented line's place:

```
$unstrung = json_decode($variable);
if(is_object($unstrung)) sanitize($unstrung);

$unstrung = json_decode($variable);
if(json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) sanitize($unstrung);

if(!is_array(json_decode($variable, true))) sanitize(json_decode($variable));
```

However, each of these ended up character encoding the quotations in strings in particular situations. For example, if I send data encoded likewise, `JSON.stringify(["data"])`, and my server sanitizes it using this function and spits it right back, I get response such as `"[&quot;data&quot;]"`. Why am I getting this?

Comment: Why are you doing this ? What is the end goal ?

Comment: I want my sanitation function to be able to recognize JSON, parse it, and sanitize the result. Trying to add this support into my function has broken how some strings are getting processed, as described at the end of my post.

Comment: .. so, you want to sanitize keys and values from unsafe html ?

Comment: Yes. Especially important as I am also hooking this up to a database.

Comment: It was not until recently that I found myself sending larger parcels of information that weren't discrete strings, making JSON, arrays, and objects a necessary means of carrying information.

Answer (score 0):

This is your criminal: `$variable = htmlspecialchars($variable);`

[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is going to chew up your double quotes like that unless you specifically flag it not to with `ENT_NOQUOTES`.

If you are most concerned about the security impact on your database with this strings, then be sure to use prepared statements with placeholders when you query with user data.

Providing an earlier (prior to your querying process) sanitizing process is difficult for us to suggest because we don't know enough about your project (that would make your question rather broad as well).

Hopefully this information will be enough to give you some traction to move forward with your project.